# Return XML in a Spring MVC controller

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have Spring MVC controller which handles the form submission. What I'm trying to do is to get the controller to return an XML to the browser upon form submission. But thymeleaf template resolver outputs an error saying that its unable to resolve the template "result"

I have a result.xml in resources > templates.

My **controller.java** as below

```
@Controller
public class WebController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/simcheck", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String greetingForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("SimilarityForm", new SimilarityForm());
        return "SimilarityForm";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/simcheck", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String greetingSubmit(@ModelAttribute SimilarityForm formData, Model model) throws IOException {

        Similarity s = new Similarity();        
        Scores scores = s.calculateSim(formData.getQuery(), formData.getReference());

        formData.setQuery("Percentage :" + scores.getLsaScore().toString());

        model.addAttribute("SimilarityForm", formData);

        return "result";
    }

}
```

However, if I rename my result.XML into result.html it works fine, and it returns a HTML template perfectly.

So does Spring actually support an XML return?

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot? The extensions searched are based on the template configuration, and I think Boot just registers `.html`.

Comment: Yes i am. I just continued the development from one of the starter tutorials (handling form submission). Besides if i use @restcontroller i can return json strings, so it seems boot supports more than just html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, Spring supports XML.

You have to use `@ResponseBody` (or `@RestController` if you are going to return XML or JSON for all controller methods) and return a JAXB-annotated object from the controller method.

Comment: Yes i ended up using RestController. Thanks

Comment: Ah, I thought @kype wanted some custom XML for the method. Built-in Spring REST support is definitely the preferable option.